# Sharepoint2010 custom list view, changing setuppath post production to new AllItems.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list definition in production environment with list instances created with the following definition:

```
<View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="All Items" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/issues.png" Url="Forms/AllItems.aspx">
```

I need to changing the setup path in some way so the AllItems.aspx view of the document library displays documents from it's parent site document library by e.g. `CQWP`.  I've attempted this by using `SPView.SetViewXml()` but this has no affect.

I have attempted to follow [Stefan Stanev's SharePoint blog](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.sg/2010/02/listviewwebpart-spview-two-sides-of.html?showComment=1320248995015#c2997993027501578245)

I've successfully changed the setup path in development with [Unghost a custom SPView](http://www.notesfor.net/post/2009/08/20/Unghost-a-custom-SPView.aspx)  but I really do not want to go down this path.

I have customized the `viewpage.aspx` by mapping to templates\pages and editting / adding the required web part and adding feature upgrading to create a new view set it as default, change the ViewXml by calling SPView.SetViewXml but this does not work.

Is there a way of updating the content database post production to change and customise AllItems.aspx of a custom document library without directly querying content database?